# Obfuscate Img Src in HTML

Tags: html, obfuscation, image, encode, src

I need a way my image sources to be hard to read.

Currently I have

```
<img id="testImg" src="http://images.mydomain.com/sample.png />
```

and I need it converted to something like:

```
<img id="testImg" src="javascript:xorDecode('3233435jh45h3232kl232kl2323', '32434mfr')"/>
```

Is this possible?

P.S. And I want to to so for around 200 KB various images.

Comment: My first question is what is the purpose of this?  If it is to prevent hotlinking, then there are better ways of doing this.

Comment: Either way, you'll be supplying the password via the source code anyways, so what's the whole point of this?

Comment: -1. All attempts to "secure" an on-line image are futile.

Comment: We are not talking about securing, we are talking about obfuscation. Yes, everybody with some novice JavaScript skills or a Firebug installed can "see" the real value but lets admit it - less than 1% of our web users are that much skilled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `xorDecode` function returns a valid URI, this will work. However, anyone with firebug will be able to see the decoded URI.

You can use the [data URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) in new browsers, this will require you to encode the image as text and embed it in the page/css.

Comment: As far as I am aware the URI has a limited length and I wish to encode around 200 KB images.

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin, in [The Gimp](http://gimp.org/), to export an image as a series of HTML `<td>`'s, one for each pixel. It is the best way to utterly obfuscate an image.

Comment: And a single printscreen solves the problem for the user, doesn't it?

Comment: +1 because it's interesting and I've never heard of it... BUT this process will be easily reversible (why not print screen!), it will increase the image size hugely (no optimisations!  Essentially a BMP with a large overhead).  Important to note, ANYTHING you put online CAN be copied and stolen.  It is also important to note that a lot of people value their pictures a lot more than they are actually worth.

Comment: I doubt that 200 KB images will ok with all those additional <td> tags. I guess the whole size will be increased to 1 MB of markup.